# Why isn't my jQuery.get() callback being called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, json, callback

I would expect the following code to display 'hi mom' between the `<div id='job-status'></div>` on the originating page, but it doesn't:

```
$(function () {
    function show_status() {
         $.get("<%= status_jobs_path -%>",
               function(data) {
                   $('#job-status').html('hi mom');
               }, 'json');
    }
    show_status();
});
```

The get() function being triggered: I see the request arrive at my server and a 200 OK response containing my JSON code.  But an alert() inside the `function(data) { ... }` body never gets called, nor is 'hi mom' displayed on the page.  However, if I strip the code down to:

```
$(function () {
    function show_status() {
        $('#job-status').html('hi mom');
    }
    show_status();
});
```

... then it does display 'hi mom' within the `<div id='job-status'></div>`.

IASISO (I Am Sure It's Something Obvious), but what am I missing?

Comment: Do you see the success result in firebug / chrome dev tools?

Comment: Are you sure the response is valid JSON? jQuery will still redirect to the `error` callback (or [`deferred.fail`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) for `$.get`) if parsing fails.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see that acronym catching on. In regards to your question, are you sure the JSON object being returned is valid and properly structured? Also, is this a same-domain request or cross-domain?

Comment: have you tried outputting to the console what the return data contained?

Comment: see below -- the problem was that I was returning mal-formed JSON, which jQuery silently drops.  So @jonathan had it right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess is that you return an invalid `json` response.  Try putting this in your controller action

```
 render :json => { :message => "Hi mom" }, :status => :ok
```

Comment: Yep -- that was it.  I've just learned that JSON doesn't accept a trailing comma in a list of elements (Ruby has spoiled me) and that jQuery.get() silently fails on mal-formed JSON.  Thanks.